# Mail Server Free Alternatives on Windows

Tags: windows, email, open-source

My company is using Microsoft Mail and the company want to upgrade the mail server, but does not have enough cash for expending on an Exchange, so I was wondering what are the free alternatives out there that permits us to:

- Configure a Mail Server for Intranet
- Configure a Mail Server for Internet (optional, not too important right now, but cool)
- Permit working with various mail clients (Outlook Express, Office Outlook, Maybe ThunderBird, something easy for users)
- Basic Mail Features (inbox, folders, attach files, groups)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend Mercury Mail System, from the makers of Pegasus mail.
http://community.pmail.com/

it's a community edition and free!

http://community.pmail.com/pmail/MercuryFeatures.aspx

Comment: Excuse me... this is the same one bundled with XAMPP?

Comment: Yes, I think you're right.

Comment: +1 for Mercury, I've been running it for almost 10 years and no issues with it. The only thing it's missing is webmail.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe hMailServer? 
http://www.hmailserver.com/

It sounds like it does what you want, but I've never used it.

Comment: +1 used it; liked it as a pop3 server. works well with ASSP as its smtp component. Integrated with ClamAv flawlessly.

Comment: Tried Hmail server before on a dedicated server for Windows hosting. It does the job but i run into corrupted database problem. It use MySQL i believe. I'm not sure about the current version but all the previous version was kind of disappointing. I end up switching over to SmarterMail.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out http://www.imailserver.com/. It's not free, but it's a full featured and **supported** product. They have a 30 day free trail available and prices start at $595.00 for 10 users.

Comment: +1 for iMail .. Ipswitch is a great company.  And the price specified includes A/V, anti-spam and instant messaging.  There are more basic versions that cost less than half.  And it doesn't have CALs!

Answer (score 1):

[MailEnable](http://www.mailenable.com/) offers free versions of their product.

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering what are the free
>   alternatives out there that permits us
>   to:

Instead of running your own mail server you should at least consider using something like [Google Apps](http://www.google.com/a) or another hosted service.  You may be able to get the service for free.  You won't have to maintain servers yourself.

Comment: I agree with the ease of maintenance by "outsourcing" the servers, but not all the users have Internet access nor they should either, so I probably need a "offline" solution

Answer (score 1):

Check out this Server Fault question for a few mail servers [What kind of mail server do you use?](https://serverfault.com/questions/722/what-kind-of-mail-server-do-you-use)

Answer (score 1):

I believe scalix supports .pst's.  This may or may not be important to you.

Answer (score 0):

Search for zarafa, zimbra, citadel, scalix....

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 alternatives:

1. Hosted Messaging Solution - Checkout Google Apps, Microsoft Exchange Online or any other 3rd party hosting solution. You will pay per mailbox, but will save greatly Hardware, Licensing (if any), Implementation and regular manitainence costs.
2. Open Source Message products - EXIM is the best. Simple & Stable.

hth's

Answer (score 0):

I will second Google Apps for Domains. I have deployed them at two client sites and it works great! It is free for up to 100 users.

google.com/apps/intl/en/business/index. html

Comment: Until, they change the TOS so now you can only have 10 free accounts.