# Best email server solutions on Windows

Tags: smtp, email-server

We are currently use mdaemon and we have over than 1000 box of email. mdaemon seen to rich is limit because is always crash.

We are looking for another email server, could be exchange or other, support imap, pop3, smtp, syncrhonize calendar

Did you have some mail server to suggest ?

I need the solutions are compatible with windows server solutions

Comment: Gordano sounds like it may be your best bet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

~1000 Mailbox's and a Windows solution. While zimbra and google are good, I'm going to give Microsoft this one.

Exchange & Windows server are built for each other. I've seen an Exchange 2000 server still running on Windows 2000 server up until mid '09... It was only replaced because they wanted to use all the new bells and whistles in Outlook 2007!

So for that volume of users, go Exchange. Server 2008 R2 is a fantastic server OS, and Exchange 2007 will do wonders!

Things to consider with exchange: I'm going to assume that they are already running an active directory environment? Are all users located in the 1 building or spread across several... if several, what is the bandwidth like? All the users will need to use Outlook... Exchange does, however, have a nice Outlook Web Access client.

Exchange works of a MAPI protocol, so if 1000 people have outlook open, that 1000 open connections to your exchange server... make sure exchange has it's own server, and plenty of CPU and memory, not to mention storage!

Whats the budget like for this too? Licensing will be the biggest cost for exchange (next to the hardware).

Comment: How cost an exchange server with all the tool ? If i got 10 000 $ to 15 000 $

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/exchange/2010/en/us/exchange-2007-how-to-buy.aspx#Pricing

Enterprise edition is $3,999 US to start with and that'll give you about 500 mail box's. Best way to get pricing is to find and call a Microsoft Partner. There should be one close to you. Checkout the partner website! https://partner.microsoft.com

Good luck with the project! it may be an expensive exercise but well worth it. Just make sure you also price up a backup system and anti-virus! The minor details people forget till after the project!

Answer (score 2):

You should consider [Zimbra](http://www.zimbra.com/). It will do every you mentionned.

Comment: Zimbra gets my vote every time this question is asked :)

Comment: I need a microsoft solutions, need a server working on Windows

Answer (score 2):

You told Antoine you need a Mircosoft solution, and if that is true, it's Exchange all the way. "imap, pop3, smtp, syncrhonize calendar", it does all that as well. There are tons of other options out, but for M$ products it is Exchange.

If you can reach out of M$, look at SmarterMail:

http://www.smartertools.com/SmarterMail/Features/Windows-Mail-Server-Software-Webmail-Exchange-Alternative.aspx

Runs on Windows just fine and it's pretty flexible.

Comment: How much cost Exchange, after installing all tools, antivirus, anti spam ... etc

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/exchange/2010/en/us/exchange-2007-how-to-buy.aspx

Get a barracuda 400: http://www.barracudanetworks.com/ns/products/spam_specs.php

If it *has* to be MS, you'll need ForeFront: http://www.microsoft.com/forefront/serversecurity/exchange/en/us/pricing-licensing.aspx

Comment: I think i good solutions could be like you said, Microsoft Exchange Standard, and a baracuda solutions. I will test that

Answer (score 1):

What about google apps enterprise?

Comment: We are mail provider for her client, so if we need to paid, for the box, it's not a good solutions for us

Comment: they do do an authorised resellers program:
http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/resellers/index.html

Answer (score 1):

[Preferred mail system/server for a company?](https://serverfault.com/questions/107595/preferred-mail-system-server-for-a-company)

Answer (score 1):

Nobody has mentioned this yet, but I'll throw [modusMail](http://www.vircom.com/) out there for consideration as well.  It's designed for Windows, is a commercially supported product, and has one of the best spam filters that I have ever seen (and they are constantly pushing down updates to the filters if you're on a support plan).  It has a lot of bells and whistles out of the box and lots of options to customize it.  The only downside is that the webmail application that it ships with is rather weak and does not support any sort of calendar or shared notes, etc. like Exchange does.  It is available as software you can download and install or as a managed appliance you can connect to your network.  It is expensive compared to some of the others mentioned but worth every penny.

Answer (score 0):

Exchange will do all you need, and will give you Active Directory integration as well (which you really should be using with 1000 mailboxes).  If you've nothing against using Exchange then I think this decision makes itself.

Answer (score 0):

SmarterMail is honestly the most affordable and a very good solution. See the [SmarterTools](http://www.smartertools.com) web site for more information. [My web host](http://www.reliablesite.net) runs this mail server and it's fast and works great.