# Simple Windows mail server recommendation

Tags: windows, email-server

We want to migrate from MDaemon to another simple mail server.

Our main requirements are:

- simplicity
- antivirus support
- we need to be able to import emails
  from MDaemon (I think it will be simply done through IMAP, right?)
- will be good if the mail server supports receiving faxes and saving
  them as mail messages
- can be commercial (we can afford several hundred bucks I think)
- Windows platform

Our use case is simple:

On the remote hosting server we have, say, 3 email addresses: mail1@company.org, mail2@company.org, mail3@company.org. And let's say we have 5 users in the company and each of them should be able to access and work with these 3 mail boxes using their mail clients, like Outlook.

We need mail server to download messages from these addresses, delete them on the remote server after downloading, and all our users would connect to the company's mail server from different workplaces and receive messages. So it will be like a shared work. One user can mark message as read and all other users on other workplaces will see it. Another user can reply to a mail message and other users will be able to see that the message is replied and see the reply in sent messages.
Well, I believe it's a standard use case in many organizations, right?

That's pretty much all we need! So, we don't need a million options and functions :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best email server solutions on Windows](http://serverfault.com/questions/114646/best-email-server-solutions-on-windows)

Comment: They mostly recommend MS Exchange there and I heard that it is a powerful mail client for big organizations who need many customizations. I am afraid it will be an overkill for us, same as MDaemon...

Comment: Product and service recommendations are specifically off topic for ServerFault (see point 4 in the NOT About section of the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thank you for your replies.
After reading many reviews and opinions we decided to take a look at hMailServer and Kerio Connect. We tried both for a few hours each and **decided to choose Kerio**, because it looks more professional (I mean overall performance, not GUI), has better logging features, has more settings and features (though not enough to scare, like MDaemon does).
So for now we are using Kerio Connect. If it dissapoints us in the future, I will update this topic :)

Comment: After almost 1 year of using - the flight is ok :)

Answer (score 2):

For small organizations my company recommends and resells [Hosted Exchange from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/exchange/en-us/exchange-online-hosted-email.aspx). All the benefits of Exchange, but with a small price tag and no SysAdmin overhead.

It's basically direct competition for solutions like [Google Apps for Business](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

hmailserver

have used a a couple years ago, and was really fine.